# FileSystem.Print has invalid arguments

Tags: c#

I am using this below code to print my bill. I am getting the following error "Filesystem.Print has invalid arguments",Please Help in overcoming this error.

```
    using Microsoft.Visualbasic;
    .......................
    public void PrintHeader()
    {
        FileSystem.Print(eInit + eCentre + "My Shop","");
        FileSystem.Print("Tel:0123 456 7890","");
        FileSystem.Print("Web: www.ame.com");
        FileSystem.Print("sales@ame.com");
        FileSystem.Print("VAT Reg No:123 4567 89" + eLeft);
        PrintDashes();
    }
```

Comment: what types are `eInit` `eCentre` `eLeft`?

Comment: all are const string

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void Print(
int FileNumber,
params Object[] Output
)
```

This is obviously a Visual Basic function. `FileNumber` is the handle of a file opened with `FileOpen` (which is a remnant of `OPEN` from Visual Basic 6.0 and older).

Example:

```
int myFileHandle = 1;
FileSystem.FileOpen(myFileHandle, "log.txt", OpenMode.Output);
FileSystem.Print(myFileHandle, "Hello", " ", "World!");
FileSystem.FileClose(myFileHandle);
```

You need to open a file with a specified handle first, and pass it into FileNumber.

Another better solution is to *not* use these API's as they are extremely outdated. Prefer the `System.IO` namespace.

**edit:**

To use the System.IO namespace instead you would open a StreamWriter:

```
var writer = new StreamWriter("mybill.txt");
```

And your `PrintHeader` method would take a `TextWriter` input (`StreamWriter` extends `TextWriter`)

```
public void PrintHeader(TextWriter output)
{
    output.WriteLine(eInit + eCentre + "My Shop");
    output.WriteLine("Tel:0123 456 7890","");
    output.WriteLine("Web: www.ame.com");
    output.WriteLine("sales@ame.com");
    output.WriteLine("VAT Reg No:123 4567 89" + eLeft);
    output.WriteLine(new string('-', 20)); 
}
```

If you're feeling adventurous you can make it async as well

```
public async Task PrintHeaderAsync(TextWriter output)
{
    await output.WriteLineAsync(eInit + eCentre + "My Shop");
    await output.WriteLineAsync("Tel:0123 456 7890","");
    await output.WriteLineAsync("Web: www.ame.com");
    await output.WriteLineAsync("sales@ame.com");
    await output.WriteLineAsync("VAT Reg No:123 4567 89" + eLeft);
    await output.WriteLineAsync(new string('-', 20));
}
```

Comment: I want to print bills through thermal printed. i got this source code from internet, I have no other go but use these API codes :(.

Comment: If I call in the PrintHeader function what would I set on the TextWriter Paramater?

Answer (score 0):

FileSystem.Print method looks like this:

```
public static void Print(
    int FileNumber,
    params Object[] Output
)
```

So you have to pass two arguments in the Print method, but in some cases you are passing only one argument, and thus you are getting that error.

Comment: I just need to print those lines inside "..". i have no idea what should be the second parameter.Can u please help?

Comment: You want to print those lines in the file right? see this link for examples: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.filesystem.print(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I want to print these as bills in thermal printer

Answer (score 0):

The question seems to be "how do I print this?"

The solution would be that you would use `System.Drawing.Printing` namespace.

I however took it as a little challenge, so I made a PrinterWriter class which you use as a normal textwriter.

The source code can be found in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/GeirGrusom/38861d595959ee270f57) and its usage is simple:

```
using(var myPrinter = new PrinterWriter())
{
  myPrinter.WriteLine("Hello World!");
}
```

You can give parameters to the constructor if you want to write to another printer or change the font (which defaults to Consolas 10pt).

The using is important because it starts printing when Dispose() is called.

Note: it doesn't do word wrap.